# XPATH cannot located @click attribute

Tags: xpath

I am trying to locate and element see below

```
<td nowrap="">
  <a onclick="GetDept(0);return false;" href="#">
    <img width="21" `hspace="0" height="21" 
         align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="" 
         src="images/cw_dept.gif">
  </a>
 </td>`
```

I have tried all the following xpath locators but to no avail

```
//*[@*='GetDept(0)']
//*[@onclick='GetDept(0)']
//*[contains(@click,'GetDept')]
```

//*[contains(.,'GetDept')

The following xpath works in that it find all matches

//*[@click]

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:
//*[contains(@onclick,'GetDept')]

Is this what you are trying to get or the  node then just look for the parent of the outcome.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: no this did not work, this worked //*[contains(@onclick,'2') and contains(@onclick,'GetDept')

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//*[starts-with(@onclick,'GetDept(0);')]
```

If that selects more than one element, this means that more context needs to be specified:

```
//td/a[starts-with(@onclick,'GetDept(0);')]
```

Or even:

```
//td/a[@onclick='GetDept(0);return false;')]
```